# Is there any way we can add our own text to the Salesforce Live Agent Transcript chat body?

Tags: liveagent, livechattranscript

Just wanted to enquire that we have a scenario where the customer is conversing with an Ai bot prior to the Live Agent redirection. On redirecting, we want the previous chat history to show up in the same Live Agent chat window, in which the user and the online agent would be carrying the conversation forward.

I looked around but apparently we can't customize the chat script. The only thing that i found was using input variables and pre-chat form, but as evident from the use case, that's not the solution here.

Is there any thing I am missing or any other way to approaching the solution for this?

Thanks in advance!